# Вставка видео .flv на сайт

Tags: html, flv

Доброго всем времени суток. Мне нужно вставить видео в формате `.flv` на сайт, но без всяких плееров, а как картинку, чтоб это видео висело и крутилось. Как это реализовать без плееров?

Comment: [переконвертировать](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=flv+to+swf) в **swf**. Как Flash-объект добавить, я ж думаю вам рассказывать не надо? )

Comment: Прочитайте про тег video и embed...

Answer (score 2):

Если бы не flv то html5 <video> подошел бы, многие современные браузеры его уже давно поддерживают. Альтернативных не плеерных вариантов для flv не существует, если только у пользователя не стоит gnash )

Comment: понятно, теперь более умным головам есть над чем подумать ))) спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Конвертировать в любой формат подходящий для HTML тега <video> (MP4). Этим занимается например Adobe Media Encoder.

Затем пишем простой вариант кода:

```
<video src="movie.mp4"></video>
```